# Copy paste Functionality in React input field with Skipping acording to Excel copied Record

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to perform copy paste functionality.

Copy the data from the excel file and Paste the record in the input field. I should be able to paste according to the respective fields. If I Copied 3*3 matrix cell from the excel and pasted the data into the 5th input field  5th 6th input should be and should skip the 7th field. continue 8th 9th similar.

I am facing problem with skipping the input field.

Code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const MultipleInputFields = () => {
    const [inputValues,
        setInputValues] = useState([
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ]);

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const {value} = e.target;
        const updatedValues = [...inputValues];
        updatedValues[
            e
                .target
                .getAttribute("attr")
        ] = value;
        setInputValues(updatedValues);
    };

    const handlePaste = (event) => {

        let pastedData = event
            .clipboardData
            .getData('text/plain');

        pastedData = pastedData.substring(0, pastedData.length - 1);

        const rows = pastedData.split('\n');

        const horizontalValues = [];
        const verticalValues = [];
        const updatedValues = [...inputValues];

        var attribute = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("attr"));
        var verticalIndex = attribute;
        var horizontalIndex = attribute;
        rows.forEach((row, indexValue) => {
            const values = row
                .split('\t')
                .map((value) => value.trim());

            if (values.length == 1) {
                for (verticalIndex; verticalIndex <= updatedValues.length;) {
                    updatedValues[verticalIndex - 1] = values[0]
                        ?.trim();
                    verticalIndex = verticalIndex + 3
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (values.length > 1) {
                var index = 0,
                    indexData = 0;
                for (var i = attribute + indexValue; i <= updatedValues.length; i++) {

                    if (index >= values.length || ((indexData == 0) && ((attribute) % 3 === 2 && attribute / 3 < 12))) {
                        //     horizontalIndex = horizontalIndex + 3 - values.length;
                        if (values.length == 2) {
                            horizontalIndex += 1;
                        } else if (values.length == 1) {
                            horizontalIndex += 2;
                        } else if ((attribute) % 3 === 2 && attribute / 3 < 12) {
                            horizontalIndex++;
                        }
                        // Break the loop if we run out of pasted values
                        break;
                    }
                    updatedValues[horizontalIndex - 1] = values[index]
                        ?.trim();
                    index++;

                    horizontalIndex++;

                }
            }
        });

       
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Your handler logic goes here You can update the state or perform any other
            // actions here
            setInputValues(updatedValues);
        }, 10);
    };

    return (
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text1`}
                    attr="1"
                    value={inputValues[0] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>
            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text2`}
                    attr="2"
                    value={inputValues[1] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text3`}
                    attr="3"
                    value={inputValues[2] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>

            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text4`}
                    attr="4"
                    value={inputValues[3] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text4`}
                    attr="5"
                    value={inputValues[4] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text4`}
                    attr="6"
                    value={inputValues[5] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text4`}
                    attr="7"
                    value={inputValues[6] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text4`}
                    attr="8"
                    value={inputValues[7] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text4`}
                    attr="9"
                    value={inputValues[8] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text4`}
                    attr="10"
                    value={inputValues[9] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>

            </div>
            <div className='col-4'>
                <input
                    name={`text4`}
                    attr="11"
                    value={inputValues[10] || ''}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                    handlePaste(e)
                }}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MultipleInputFields;
```

Copy Paste Functionality in the React Input field